# Type string[] is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass the prop of `todos` just like in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-fog-e58oo), but I'm getting an error:

```
Type '{ todos: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.
Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.ts(2322)
```

I already declared a `Context` but out of curiosity I want to try using Props so I can compare which is better in terms of performance.

**Note:**
I have already tried to use this technique:

```
const ListProps = {
  todos
};

<List {...ListProps} />
```

but to no avail because I'm not sure how can I access the parameter in the `List` component.

```
const List = (todos: string[]) => {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with Typescript and React, you will need to explicitly type your functional component.

First, you may define a type alias or interface for your component:

```
interface ListProps {
  todos: string[]
}
```

Then, we type your List component as `React.FC`, with the props interface as part of the generics:

```
const List: React.FC<ListProps> = ({ todos }) => {...}
```

This should solve the errors raised by the typescript compiler when you import the List on a parent component..

Comment: @jt25 anyways, do check this out! https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide

Comment: I'll definitely look into it. In your experience, what do you prefer, Hooks Context or Props ?

Comment: @jt25 I've used both, but I don't think I have a clear preference :) I am not sure which one is better when it comes to performance too.